# Does prefetching works with a post shortlink?

Tags: wordpress, prefetch

I want to prefetch the next post in WordPress. In the admin panel and in the **Permalink** settings, permalinks are set to show **Day and name**:

> example.com/2021/12/25/post-1

Does prefetching works using a post short permalink:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="http://example.com/?p=1">
```

instead of the regular post permalink:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="http://example.com/2021/12/25/post-1">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are pointing to the same `text/html` request. The short permalink `?p=1` is actually a [`301` HTTP status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301) code permanent redirect towards the regular permalink.

---

### `prefetch` through the short permalink (eg: `/?p=1`)

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="http://localhost/www/wordpress/?p=1">
```

As it is a `301`, you will prefetch both. 2 different `text/html` request will be made.

[image]

You can have a look at the network chrome console tab to test it on your own.

---

### `prefetch` through the regular permalink (eg: `/hello-world/`)

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="http://localhost/www/wordpress/hello-world/">
```

Only 1 `text/html` request will be made.

---

### In short

Both are doing exactly the same thing. One is more direct, and less performances heavy than the other.

You should have a look at the [Prefetch MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Prefetch) and the [Link prefetching FAQ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ) to have a better understanding on how `prefetch` actually works.